# How do I fix the glxinfo BadValue error on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am getting the following error but have no idea how to fix it.

**Error**

```
glxinfo
name of display: :0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  96
  Current serial number in output stream:  97
```

**Packages**

```
i  libnvidia-gl-440 - NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
i  libnvidia-gl-440:i386 - NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
```

I have tried downgrading the drivers but did not work. Most solutions on the web involve putting a 32-bit driver, but I already have one. I have the same problem when I run `glxgears` too.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), but that's also your problem. Being EOL, mirrors can drop the release, and the main archive moves to old-releases.  Your tested & supported *release-upgrade* path is now also gone, as 18.10 upgraded to 19 04 which now too is EOL. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Comment: Its actually 18.04 per https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: Reviewers: Ubuntu 18.10 **is** End of Life.  However, at the original time of posting, the OP referred to 18.10 and not 18.04.  **Please do not flag comments on this post as "Not accurate" regarding guiverc's post about 18.10 being End of Life.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04, but adding the user to the `video` group as suggested in the other answer did not help for me.

Instead, I needed to install the correct drivers using the method described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux).

- `ubuntu-drivers devices` to detect graphics card and recommended drivers
- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install recommended drivers
- `sudo apt autoremove` to remove redundant packages
- reboot
- `glxgears` worked for me.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Worked for me as well on 22.10, thank you.

Comment: Solved my problems with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just had this issue in an updated 20.04 with NVidia, and this was the first search result. Later I found the solution in the old X-Plane forums: https://questions.x-plane.com/5090/linux-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-operation?show=5146#c5146

Our user account must be included in the **`video`** group: `sudo adduser $USER video`